# Pointers pointing to same memory location but different program

Tags: c++, pointers

I've written two programs, one (p1.cpp) that prints the value and address of a variable every 1 second..

```
// p1.cpp
int main() {

    int x = 13;
    int *p = &x;
    
    while (true) {
        cout << " value of x: " << *p << " addr: " << p << endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

and the other (p2.cpp), in which I manually point a pointer to the location printed out by p1.cpp and change the value.

```
//p2.cpp
int main() {
    
    int *p = (int*)0x61ff08; // this is manually set and compiled.
    cout << "value of p from p2.cpp : " <<  *p << endl;
    *p = 10;
    
}
```

However, upon running p1.cpp, setting the location and running p2.cpp, the value in first program doesn't seem to change. In fact, p2.cpp shows some garbage value if I display the contents of p.

[output of p1.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bCZQ.png)

[output of p2.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ACst.png)

I would like to know why is this happening and why the value of x isn't changed by the pointer of another program.

Thanks!

Comment: Copy/paste the output here, it'll make the question more easily readable.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unless you are mixing C and C++ please only tag the language you are using. They are very different languages.

Comment: Each program has its own virtual memory. Pointers point to that virtual memory (provided by OS), not to physical memory. The same address in two programs will always point to different physical memory.

Comment: You might read about virtual memory. Same address values in different processes doesn't mean that they address same memory location.

Comment: consider what happens when you run p1 twice, you might get the same adress printed twice. This alone can tell you that it doesnt quite work as you expect.

Comment: What is your OS ? Are you trying to modifiy the memory of a program, from another ?

Comment: @Gerhardh hello, I'll make sure to keep relevant tags for my future questions, this question is applicable for both C adn C++ and hence I added both the tags. Also, I didn't know virtual space exists for these programs as well. Thankyou!

Comment: @Fryz OS: Windows 10. Yes, I was trying to modify memory of one program from another.

Comment: @Aswinpr if your process has the right permissions you can use [WriteProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory) to write to the memory of another process. But as mentioned by others, if you want to communicate between programs, more typical structured IPC methods are preferable.

Comment: Try this on DOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In modern operating systems like linux, windows or MacOs each process has its own virtual memory address space.
Therefore the memory address from the process of your program p1 has nothing to do with the memory of the process of your program p2.

If you really want to access memory between processes directly you need to use *shared memory*.

But what is your intention? Do you just want to play around, or do you want communication between processes? In the later case you should read about IPC - inter process communication. There are a lot of IPC mechanisms you can use like named pipes, sockets or shared memory, depending on what you want to achieve.

You may have a look at this article for first introduction into the topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Comment: I was just playing around to see if its possible to alter memory of other programs. I didn't know that every process will have it's own virtual memory (I thought it's a thing for languages such as Java).

Comment: @Aswinpr It is possible if you are on an OS with non-virtual memory (=single address space operating system) like DOS for example or you use an exploit to direcly access memory of other processes (programs). Java is another thing, because it runs on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) mostly (though there are versions which don't).